# PHP Regex to get youtube video ID?

Tags: php, regex

Can someone show me how to get the youtube id out of a url regardless of what other GET variables are in the URL.

Use this video for example: `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4kxS1ksqtw&feature=related`

So between `v=` and before the next `&`

Comment: That might be helpful

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522868/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-id-php

Comment: You should look at my code https://github.com/lingtalfi/video-ids-and-thumbnails/blob/master/testvideo.php, I provide functions that extract id from youtube, vimeo and dailymotion.

Comment: @ling in function getVideoThumbnailByUrl() you were using the deprecated file_get_contents() for Vimeo.  This replacement will work everywhere:
`$ch=curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/$id.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
$hash =unserialize(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close($ch);`

Comment: @ling Also in getYoutubeId($url) the final conditional will accept any string and validate it as a YT id.  I passed it 'junk' and it returned junk as an id parsed from that string.

Comment: @jerrygarciuh: afaik file_get_contents is not deprecated, feel free to report an issue on github if you had problem with this function. Thanks for spotting the error in getYoutubeId (I enhanced it).

Comment: @ling - you are correct.  The correct phrasing would be that file_get_contents is very commonly disabled by hosts as a security risk.

Answer (score 340, accepted):

[Use parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [parse_str()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

(You can use regexes for just about anything, but they are very easy to make an error in, so if there are PHP functions specifically for what you are trying to accomplish, use those.)

parse_url takes a string and cuts it up into an array that has a bunch of info. You can work with this array, or you can specify the one item you want as a second argument. In this case we're interested in the query, which is `PHP_URL_QUERY`.

Now we have the query, which is `v=C4kxS1ksqtw&feature=relate`, but we only want the part after `v=`. For this we turn to `parse_str` which basically works like `GET` on a string. It takes a string and creates the variables specified in the string. In this case `$v` and `$feature` is created. We're only interested in `$v`.

To be safe, you don't want to just store all the variables from the `parse_url` in your namespace (see mellowsoon's comment). Instead store the variables as elements of an array, so that you have control over what variables you are storing, and you cannot accidentally overwrite an existing variable.

Putting everything together, we have:

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4kxS1ksqtw&feature=relate";
parse_str( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $my_array_of_vars );
echo $my_array_of_vars['v'];    
  // Output: C4kxS1ksqtw
?>
```

[**Working example**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/7TmHqr)

---

Edit:

hehe - thanks Charles. That made me laugh, I've never seen the Zawinski quote before:

*`Some people, when confronted with a problem, think ‘I know, I’ll use regular expressions.’  Now they have two problems.`*
– *Jamie Zawinski*

Comment: Although it doesn't use regex (at least visibly - I'm not sure how `parse_url()` works under the hood), this is the way to go.

Comment: <Insert Zawinski Quote Here>.  Though in all seriousness, using language functions to perform a task is frequently going to be better than the hoop jumping that a good regex can require.

Comment: I'd only suggest using parse_str()'s second parameter to store the query params in an array. Having variables magically appear out of thin air is never a good idea.

Comment: A quick simple example of why using parse_str()'s "magic variables" isn't a good idea -> http://pastebin.com/AtaaPH4r

Comment: @Qualcuno - of course not. This is specifically for retrieving "get variables" - per the OP. Your examples are not get variables.

Comment: @PeterAjtai indeed. Just clarifying :)

Comment: I found here a solution that includes more youtube urls forms: https://gist.github.com/ghalusa/6c7f3a00fd2383e5ef33

Comment: This saved my day : https://gist.github.com/astockwell/11055104

Comment: This example does works with URL youtu.be

Answer (score 176):

```
preg_match("#(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=v\/)[^&\n]+|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+|(?<=youtu.be/)[^&\n]+#", $url, $matches);
```

This will account for

```
youtube.com/v/{vidid}
youtube.com/vi/{vidid}
youtube.com/?v={vidid}
youtube.com/?vi={vidid}
youtube.com/watch?v={vidid}
youtube.com/watch?vi={vidid}
youtu.be/{vidid}
```

I improved it slightly to support:
http://www.youtube.com/v/5xADESocujo?feature=autoshare&version=3&autohide=1&autoplay=1

The line I use now is:

```
preg_match("#(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=v\/)[^&\n]+(?=\?)|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+|(?<=youtu.be/)[^&\n]+#", $link, $matches);
```

Comment: I have updated it to also handle URLs like this: http://www.youtube.com/embed/7zuAOomfiCc
`#(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=v\/)[^&\n]+(?=\?)|(?<=embed/)[^&\n]+|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+|(?<=youtu.be/)[^&\n]+#`

Comment: Arun SS's comment: "@SimonBS, `#(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=v\/)[^&\n]+(?=\?)|(?<=embed/)[^&\n]+|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+|(?<=youtu.be/)[^&\‌​n]+#` is not working perfectly for embed codes. It is appending remaining parts of the URLs. The output is seems like this: `45EFxhTeKwy" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>` How to strip the remaining parts?"

Comment: This works for all urls, inc embed strings `(?<=(?:v|i)=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=(?:v|i)\/)[^&\n]+|(?<=embed\/)[^"&\n]+|(?<=(?:v|i)=)[^&\n]+|(?<=youtu.be\/)[^&\n]+` http://rubular.com/r/M9PJYcQxRW

Comment: how about this /(youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(watch\?(.*&)?v=|(embed|v|user)\/))([^\?&"'>]+)/

Comment: @bokor It does't work as expected. It just grabs the whole URL, not just the ID. So far, Rob's solution is the one that works best for all cases.

Comment: Actually @bokor's code populates the `$matches` array with more info, including the video ID which was very useful for my project

Comment: Addition to the regex of Rob, &list was captured as well. This is stripped out in the regex below: #(?<=(?:v|i)=)[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+|(?<=(?:v|i)\/)[^&?\n]+|(?<=embed\/)[^"&?\n]+|(?<=‌​(?:v|i)=)[^&?\n]+|(?<=youtu.be\/)[^&?\n]+# Now supported: http://youtu.be/RRyG_mtYieI?list=PLnBXpb1YLPttKF7RZX64qI_AEyFjTvgtx https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRyG_mtYieI&index=4&list=PLnBXpb1YLPttKF7RZX64qI‌​_AEyFjTvgtx //www.youtube.com/embed/RRyG_mtYieI?list=PLnBXpb1YLPttKF7RZX64qI_AEyFjTvgtx http://www.youtube.com/v/RRyG_mtYieI

Answer (score 124):

*Based on bokor's comment on Anthony's answer:*

```
preg_match("/^(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:m\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:(?:watch)?\?(?:.*&)?v(?:i)?=|(?:embed|v|vi|user|shorts)\/))([^\?&\"'>]+)/", $url, $matches);
```

`$matches[1]` contains the vidid

Matches:

- `youtube.com/v/vidid`
- `youtube.com/vi/vidid`
- `youtube.com/?v=vidid`
- `youtube.com/?vi=vidid`
- `youtube.com/watch?v=vidid`
- `youtube.com/watch?vi=vidid`
- `youtu.be/vidid`
- `youtube.com/embed/vidid`
- `http://youtube.com/v/vidid`
- `http://www.youtube.com/v/vidid`
- `https://www.youtube.com/v/vidid`
- `youtube.com/watch?v=vidid&wtv=wtv`
- `http://www.youtube.com/watch?dev=inprogress&v=vidid&feature=related`
- `https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=vidid`
- `youtube.com/shorts/vidid`

Does not match:

- `www.facebook.com?wtv=youtube.com/v/vidid`

Comment: Do you have a C/objc/c++ version of this string? i don't know which parts to escape.

Comment: I tried: "^(?:http(?:s)?://)?(?:www\\.)?(?:youtu\\.be/|youtube\\.com/(?:(?:watch)?\?(?:.*&)?v(?:i)?=|(?:embed|v|vi|user)/))([^\?&\"'>]+)"

Not passing all your examples

Comment: I found my problem. here it is the final c string: "^(?:http(?:s)?://)?(?:www\\.)?(?:youtu\\.be/|youtube\\.com/(?:(?:watch)?\\?(?:.*&)?v(?:i)?=|(?:embed|v|vi|user)/))([^\?&\"'>]+)"

Comment: To also take into account urls like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vidid#action=share I have added the `#` to the ending capture group: `preg_match("/^(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:m\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:(?:watch)?\?(?:.*&)?v(?:i)?=|(?:embed|v|vi|user)\/))([^\?#&\"'>]+)/", $url, $matches);`

Comment: It add content with space and grab all the text after a url on a page. This is better /(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:m\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:(?:watch)?\?(?:.*&)?v(?:i)?=|(?:embed|v|vi|user)\/))([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*)/

Answer (score 43):

This can be very easily accomplished using [parse_str](https://www.php.net/parse_str) and [parse_url](https://www.php.net/parse_url) and is more reliable in my opinion.

My function supports the following urls:

- http://youtube.com/v/dQw4w9WgXcQ?feature=youtube_gdata_player
- http://youtube.com/vi/dQw4w9WgXcQ?feature=youtube_gdata_player
- http://youtube.com/?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player
- http://youtube.com/?vi=dQw4w9WgXcQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player
- http://youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player
- http://youtube.com/watch?vi=dQw4w9WgXcQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player
- http://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ?feature=youtube_gdata_player

Also includes the test below the function.

```
/**
 * Get Youtube video ID from URL
 *
 * @param string $url
 * @return mixed Youtube video ID or FALSE if not found
 */
function getYoutubeIdFromUrl($url) {
    $parts = parse_url($url);
    if(isset($parts['query'])){
        parse_str($parts['query'], $qs);
        if(isset($qs['v'])){
            return $qs['v'];
        }else if(isset($qs['vi'])){
            return $qs['vi'];
        }
    }
    if(isset($parts['path'])){
        $path = explode('/', trim($parts['path'], '/'));
        return $path[count($path)-1];
    }
    return false;
}
// Test
$urls = array(
    'http://youtube.com/v/dQw4w9WgXcQ?feature=youtube_gdata_player',
    'http://youtube.com/vi/dQw4w9WgXcQ?feature=youtube_gdata_player',
    'http://youtube.com/?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player',
    'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player',
    'http://youtube.com/?vi=dQw4w9WgXcQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player',
    'http://youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player',
    'http://youtube.com/watch?vi=dQw4w9WgXcQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player',
    'http://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ?feature=youtube_gdata_player'
);
foreach($urls as $url){
    echo $url . ' : ' . getYoutubeIdFromUrl($url) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: This is really great and actually works for vimeo videos as well

Comment: This is also my preferred answer. It does cover both YouTube and Vimeo. One note, I did add a super minor tweak with an additional isset() - else if(isset($qs['vi'])). Many thanks for this.

Answer (score 25):

**SOLTUION For any link type!!**:

```
<?php
function get_youtube_id_from_url($url)  {
     preg_match('/(http(s|):|)\/\/(www\.|)yout(.*?)\/(embed\/|watch.*?v=|)([a-z_A-Z0-9\-]{11})/i', $url, $results);    return $results[6];
}


echo get_youtube_id_from_url('http://www.youtube.com/watch?var1=blabla#v=GvJehZx3eQ1$var2=bla');
      // or                   http://youtu.be/GvJehZx3eQ1 
      // or                   http://www.youtube.com/embed/GvJehZx3eQ1
      // or                   http://www.youtu.be/GvJehZx3eQ1/blabla?xyz
?>
```

**outputs:** `GvJehZx3eQ1`

Comment: Beware using this to match any YT URL: for a link in the form `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9E6F57s-V7U&ab_channel=Accent%27sWayEnglishwithHadar` `$results[0]` will not contain the full link, just the part until the video id. [This helped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27969087/1717535).

Answer (score 15):

fixed based on [How to validate youtube video ids?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742813/how-to-validate-youtube-video-ids?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

```
<?php

$links = [
    "youtube.com/v/tFad5gHoBjY",
    "youtube.com/vi/tFad5gHoBjY",
    "youtube.com/?v=tFad5gHoBjY",
    "youtube.com/?vi=tFad5gHoBjY",
    "youtube.com/watch?v=tFad5gHoBjY",
    "youtube.com/watch?vi=tFad5gHoBjY",
    "youtu.be/tFad5gHoBjY",
    "http://youtu.be/qokEYBNWA_0?t=30m26s",
    "youtube.com/v/vidid",
    "youtube.com/vi/vidid",
    "youtube.com/?v=vidid",
    "youtube.com/?vi=vidid",
    "youtube.com/watch?v=vidid",
    "youtube.com/watch?vi=vidid",
    "youtu.be/vidid",
    "youtube.com/embed/vidid",
    "http://youtube.com/v/vidid",
    "http://www.youtube.com/v/vidid",
    "https://www.youtube.com/v/vidid",
    "youtube.com/watch?v=vidid&wtv=wtv",
    "http://www.youtube.com/watch?dev=inprogress&v=vidid&feature=related",
    "youtube.com/watch?v=7HCZvhRAk-M"
];

foreach($links as $link){
    preg_match("#([\/|\?|&]vi?[\/|=]|youtu\.be\/|embed\/)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)#", $link, $matches);
    var_dump(end($matches));
}
```

Answer (score 14):

The following will work for all youtube links

```
<?php
    // Here is a sample of the URLs this regex matches: (there can be more content after the given URL that will be ignored)
    // http://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ
    // http://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ
    // http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
    // http://www.youtube.com/?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
    // http://www.youtube.com/v/dQw4w9WgXcQ
    // http://www.youtube.com/e/dQw4w9WgXcQ
    // http://www.youtube.com/user/username#p/u/11/dQw4w9WgXcQ
    // http://www.youtube.com/sandalsResorts#p/c/54B8C800269D7C1B/0/dQw4w9WgXcQ
    // http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
    // http://www.youtube.com/?feature=player_embedded&v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
    // It also works on the youtube-nocookie.com URL with the same above options.
    // It will also pull the ID from the URL in an embed code (both iframe and object tags)

$url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2_MLFVdlQM";

    preg_match('%(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})%i', $url, $match);

    $youtube_id = $match[1];

echo $youtube_id;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 13):

For extracting the `id` in a capturing group, the following expression or some derivative of that might be an option too:

```
(?im)\b(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:w{3}\.)?youtu(?:be)?\.(?:com|be)\/(?:(?:\??v=?i?=?\/?)|watch\?vi?=|watch\?.*?&v=|embed\/|)([A-Z0-9_-]{11})\S*(?=\s|$)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MVA5f9/1/)

#### Test

```
$re = '/(?im)\b(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:w{3}\.)?youtu(?:be)?\.(?:com|be)\/(?:(?:\??v=?i?=?\/?)|watch\?vi?=|watch\?.*?&v=|embed\/|)([A-Z0-9_-]{11})\S*(?=\s|$)/';
$str = 'http://youtube.com/v/tFad5gHoBjY
https://youtube.com/vi/tFad5gHoBjY
http://www.youtube.com/?v=tFad5gHoBjY
http://www.youtube.com/?vi=tFad5gHoBjY
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tFad5gHoBjY
youtube.com/watch?vi=tFad5gHoBjY
youtu.be/tFad5gHoBjY
http://youtu.be/qokEYBNWA_0?t=30m26s
youtube.com/v/7HCZvhRAk-M
youtube.com/vi/7HCZvhRAk-M
youtube.com/?v=7HCZvhRAk-M
youtube.com/?vi=7HCZvhRAk-M
youtube.com/watch?v=7HCZvhRAk-M
youtube.com/watch?vi=7HCZvhRAk-M
youtu.be/7HCZvhRAk-M
youtube.com/embed/7HCZvhRAk-M
http://youtube.com/v/7HCZvhRAk-M
http://www.youtube.com/v/7HCZvhRAk-M
https://www.youtube.com/v/7HCZvhRAk-M
youtube.com/watch?v=7HCZvhRAk-M&wtv=wtv
http://www.youtube.com/watch?dev=inprogress&v=7HCZvhRAk-M&feature=related
youtube.com/watch?v=7HCZvhRAk-M
http://youtube.com/v/dQw4w9WgXcQ?feature=youtube_gdata_player
http://youtube.com/vi/dQw4w9WgXcQ?feature=youtube_gdata_player
http://youtube.com/?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player
http://youtube.com/?vi=dQw4w9WgXcQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player
http://youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player
http://youtube.com/watch?vi=dQw4w9WgXcQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player
http://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ?feature=youtube_gdata_player';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

#### Output

```
array(30) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(32) "http://youtube.com/v/tFad5gHoBjY"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "tFad5gHoBjY"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(34) "https://youtube.com/vi/tFad5gHoBjY"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "tFad5gHoBjY"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(37) "http://www.youtube.com/?v=tFad5gHoBjY"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "tFad5gHoBjY"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(38) "http://www.youtube.com/?vi=tFad5gHoBjY"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "tFad5gHoBjY"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(43) "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tFad5gHoBjY"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "tFad5gHoBjY"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(32) "youtube.com/watch?vi=tFad5gHoBjY"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "tFad5gHoBjY"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(20) "youtu.be/tFad5gHoBjY"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "tFad5gHoBjY"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(27) "http://youtu.be/qokEYBNWA_0"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "qokEYBNWA_0"
  }
  [8]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(25) "youtube.com/v/7HCZvhRAk-M"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "7HCZvhRAk-M"
  }
  [9]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(26) "youtube.com/vi/7HCZvhRAk-M"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "7HCZvhRAk-M"
  }
  [10]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(26) "youtube.com/?v=7HCZvhRAk-M"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "7HCZvhRAk-M"
  }
  [11]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(27) "youtube.com/?vi=7HCZvhRAk-M"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "7HCZvhRAk-M"
  }
  [12]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(31) "youtube.com/watch?v=7HCZvhRAk-M"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "7HCZvhRAk-M"
  }
  [13]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(32) "youtube.com/watch?vi=7HCZvhRAk-M"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "7HCZvhRAk-M"
  }
  [14]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(20) "youtu.be/7HCZvhRAk-M"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "7HCZvhRAk-M"
  }
  [15]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(29) "youtube.com/embed/7HCZvhRAk-M"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "7HCZvhRAk-M"
  }
  [16]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(32) "http://youtube.com/v/7HCZvhRAk-M"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "7HCZvhRAk-M"
  }
  [17]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(36) "http://www.youtube.com/v/7HCZvhRAk-M"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "7HCZvhRAk-M"
  }
  [18]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(37) "https://www.youtube.com/v/7HCZvhRAk-M"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "7HCZvhRAk-M"
  }
  [19]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(31) "youtube.com/watch?v=7HCZvhRAk-M"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "7HCZvhRAk-M"
  }
  [20]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(57) "http://www.youtube.com/watch?dev=inprogress&v=7HCZvhRAk-M"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "7HCZvhRAk-M"
  }
  [21]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(31) "youtube.com/watch?v=7HCZvhRAk-M"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "7HCZvhRAk-M"
  }
  [22]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(32) "http://youtube.com/v/dQw4w9WgXcQ"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "dQw4w9WgXcQ"
  }
  [23]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(33) "http://youtube.com/vi/dQw4w9WgXcQ"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "dQw4w9WgXcQ"
  }
  [24]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(33) "http://youtube.com/?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "dQw4w9WgXcQ"
  }
  [25]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(42) "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "dQw4w9WgXcQ"
  }
  [26]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(34) "http://youtube.com/?vi=dQw4w9WgXcQ"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "dQw4w9WgXcQ"
  }
  [27]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(38) "http://youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "dQw4w9WgXcQ"
  }
  [28]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(39) "http://youtube.com/watch?vi=dQw4w9WgXcQ"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "dQw4w9WgXcQ"
  }
  [29]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(27) "http://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "dQw4w9WgXcQ"
  }
}
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/thcLRa/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/thcLRa/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

---

Answer (score 11):

We know that video ID is 11 chars length and can be preceded by `v=` or `vi=` or `v/` or `vi/` or `youtu.be/`. So the simplest way to do this:

```
<?php
$youtube = 'http://youtube.com/v/dQw4w9WgXcQ?feature=youtube_gdata_player
http://youtube.com/vi/dQw4w9WgXcQ?feature=youtube_gdata_player
http://youtube.com/?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player
http://youtube.com/?vi=dQw4w9WgXcQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player
http://youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player
http://youtube.com/watch?vi=dQw4w9WgXcQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player
http://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ?feature=youtube_gdata_player';

preg_match_all("#(?<=v=|v\/|vi=|vi\/|youtu.be\/)[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11}#", $youtube, $matches);

var_dump($matches[0]);
```

And output:

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "dQw4w9WgXcQ"
  [1]=>
  string(11) "dQw4w9WgXcQ"
  [2]=>
  string(11) "dQw4w9WgXcQ"
  [3]=>
  string(11) "dQw4w9WgXcQ"
  [4]=>
  string(11) "dQw4w9WgXcQ"
  [5]=>
  string(11) "dQw4w9WgXcQ"
  [6]=>
  string(11) "dQw4w9WgXcQ"
  [7]=>
  string(11) "dQw4w9WgXcQ"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if (preg_match('![?&]{1}v=([^&]+)!', $url . '&', $m))
    $video_id = $m[1];
```

Comment: Thanks, This worked good for me since i wanted all domains, http and https, and any kind of other crap in the url.

Answer (score 5):

```
(?<=\?v=)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]){11}
```

This should do it as well.

Answer (score 5):

I had some post content I had to cipher throughout to get the Youtube ID out of. It happened to be in the form of the `<iframe>` embed code Youtube provides.

```
 <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Zpk8pMz_Kgw?rel=0" frameborder="0" width="620" height="360"></iframe>
```

The following pattern I got from @rob above. The snippet does a `foreach` loop once the matches are found, and for a added bonus I linked it to the preview image found on Youtube. It could potentially match more types of Youtube embed types and urls:

```
$pattern = '#(?<=(?:v|i)=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=(?:v|i)\/)[^&\n]+|(?<=embed\/)[^"&\n]+|(?<=‌​(?:v|i)=)[^&\n]+|(?<=youtu.be\/)[^&\n]+#';

preg_match_all($pattern, $post_content, $matches);

foreach ($matches as $match) {
    $img = "<img src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/".str_replace('?rel=0','', $match[0])."/0.jpg' />";
    break;
}
```

Rob's profile: https://stackoverflow.com/users/149615/rob

Answer (score 3):

```
$vid = preg_replace('/^.*(\?|\&)v\=/', '', $url);  // Strip all meuk before and including '?v=' or '&v='.

$vid = preg_replace('/[^\w\-\_].*$/', '', $vid);  // Strip trailing meuk.
```

Answer (score 2):

I know that the title of the thread refers to the use of a regex, but just as the Zawinski quote says, I really think that avoiding regexes is best here. I'd recommend this function instead:

```
function get_youtube_id($url)
{
    if (strpos( $url,"v=") !== false)
    {
        return substr($url, strpos($url, "v=") + 2, 11);
    }
    elseif(strpos( $url,"embed/") !== false)
    {
        return substr($url, strpos($url, "embed/") + 6, 11);
    }

}
```

I recommend this because the ID of YouTube videos is always the same, independent from the style of the URL, e.g.

- `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t_uW44Bsezg`
- `http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=endscreen&v=Id3xG4xnOfA&NR=1`
- `And Other Ulr Form In Which The Word "embed/" Is Placed Before The Id ... !!

and that might be the case for embedded and `iframe`-ed stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code :

```
$url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4kxS1ksqtw&feature=related"; 
$parse = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY); 
parse_str($parse, $output); 
echo $output['watch'];
```

result : `C4kxS1ksqtw`

Answer (score 0):

Just found this online at http://snipplr.com/view/62238/get-youtube-video-id-very-robust/

```
function getYouTubeId($url) {
// Format all domains to http://domain for easier URL parsing
str_replace('https://', 'http://', $url);
if (!stristr($url, 'http://') && (strlen($url) != 11)) {
    $url = 'http://' . $url;
}
$url = str_replace('http://www.', 'http://', $url);

if (strlen($url) == 11) {
    $code = $url;
} else if (preg_match('/http:\/\/youtu.be/', $url)) {
    $url = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
    $code = substr($url, 1, 11);
} else if (preg_match('/watch/', $url)) {
    $arr = parse_url($url);
    parse_str($url);
    $code = isset($v) ? substr($v, 0, 11) : false;
} else if (preg_match('/http:\/\/youtube.com\/v/', $url)) {
    $url = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
    $code = substr($url, 3, 11);
} else if (preg_match('/http:\/\/youtube.com\/embed/', $url, $matches)) {
    $url = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
    $code = substr($url, 7, 11);
} else if (preg_match("#(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=[0-9]/)[^&\n]+|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+#", $url, $matches) ) {
    $code = substr($matches[0], 0, 11);
} else {
    $code = false;
}

if ($code && (strlen($code) < 11)) {
    $code = false;
}

return $code;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the data from [Shawn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17030234) but generalized and shortened the regex a little. The key difference with this one is that it won't test for a valid Youtube URL, it'll just look for a video ID. Meaning it will still return a video ID for `www.facebook.com?wtv=youtube.com/v/vidid`. Works for all the test cases, but is a bit more lax. Consequently, it will output a false positive for something like `https://www.twitter.com/watch?v=vidid`. Use this method if the data is super inconsistent, otherwise use a more specific regex or `parse_url()` and `parse_str()`.

```
preg_match("/([\?&\/]vi?|embed|\.be)[\/=]([\w-]+)/",$url,$matches);
print($matches[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do this.

```php
<?php
  $video = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u00FY9vADfQ';
  $parsed_video = parse_url($video, PHP_URL_QUERY);
  parse_str($parsed_video, $arr);
?>
<iframe
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $arr['v'];  ?>"
frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

and what if I want to extract a youtue url from a string full of other characters? like this:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cPW9Y94BJI0** laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

and get https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cPW9Y94BJI0 from that string?