# ElseIf Custom Field different value (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, field

(sorry for my English) and I hope to explain!

I'm looking for a solution to display different output for a custom filed, named "cw". The my theme of much use in custom filed, so I created a function to simplify your calls:

```
/**
* Get custom field of the current page
* $type = string|int
*/
function my_getcustomfield($filedname, $page_current_id = NULL)
{
if($page_current_id==NULL)
$page_current_id = get_page_id();
$value = get_post_meta($page_current_id, $filedname, true);
return $value;
}
```

said this, I created the custom filed in my theme:

```
<?php $video_code = my_getcustomfield('cw',get_the_ID()); if(!empty($video_code)) : ?>
<div class="video_code"><?php echo $video_code; ?></div>
```

Since the custom value is a URL, type: http://127.0.0.1:4001/?f=cadbe2676d5108523f931a68eedb3582, I need to extract just the ID. using this technique [PHP Regex to get youtube video ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392993/php-regex-to-get-youtube-video-id/3393008#3393008), I modified my custom filed in this way:

```
<?php $video_code = my_getcustomfield('cw',get_the_ID()); $url = $video_code; parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY )); if(isset($video_code[0])){ ?>  
<div cacaolink="http://127.0.0.1:4001/?f=<?php echo $f; ?>"></div>
<?php } else { ?> 
<?php echo 'Video n.d.'; ?></div>
<?php endif; } ?>
```

In this way everything works perfectly.

Now, the custom value can be those listed below:

```
<div cacaolink="http://127.0.0.1:4001/megavideo/megavideo.caml?videoid="></div>
<div cacaolink="http://127.0.0.1:4001/videobb/videobb.caml?videoid="></div>
<div cacaolink="http://127.0.0.1:4001/?f="></div>
```

**Finally here is the problem: How can I use an elseif according to the custom value?

any help is appreciated :)**

Comment: So what you need in short is extracting "video id" part from urls having one of 3 structures defined above, right? If yes, all you need is the next:

Answer (score 0):

So what you need in short is extracting "video id" part from urls having one of 3 structures defined above. If I understood you right, you can just use the next code:

```
    $video_id = preg_replace("/.*\?(videoid|f)=/", '', $customvalue);
```

Where `$customvalue` is the value extracted from your custom field with `my_getcustomfield`.

Comment: thank you for your response. but the video ID can also get it with my method: `<?php echo $f; $videoid; ?>` the problem is to get these parts: /megavideo/megavideo.caml?videoid=, /videobb/videobb.caml?videoid=