# Help w/ PHP Function (Whitespace)

Tags: php, function, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to use PHP to trim a YouTube URL down to the video ID. It's working, but it's also adding a lot of whitespace to the result. Does anyone know how I'd be able to fix this? Here's the setup:

Located in Wordpress single.php (finds attached YouTube URL from post meta):

```
<?php   
$vidurl = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_videoembed", true );
$youtube_id = getYouTubeIdFromURL($vidurl);
echo $youtube_id;          
?>
```

Here's what's executing the function:

```
//Get YT Video ID
function getYouTubeIdFromURL($url)
{
  $url_string = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
  parse_str($url_string, $args);
  return isset($args['v']) ? $args['v'] : false;
}
```

Like I said, the function works fine, but it produces a bunch of white space. Say the video included in the meta is `youtube.com/watch?v=1337&feature=player_embedded` it'll return

```
"                1337    "
```

I appreciate all help in advance! I've had some really nice people help me on this site before.

Comment: Your code returns only a number http://ideone.com/ZIqRI

Comment: I know, it's supposed to return the video ID (string of 11 characters). For the demo I only used '1337.'

Comment: but it does return only a number, without spaces. So it works expectedly

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Regex to get youtube video ID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392993/php-regex-to-get-youtube-video-id)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your `get_post_meta` function isn't returning a bunch of spaces with it?  Can you do a `var_dump` on `$vidurl`?  When I run the function you gave, the output looks just fine (http://www.ideone.com/LRoTd):

```
<?php
    function getYouTubeIdFromURL($url)
    {
        $url_string = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
        parse_str($url_string, $args);
        return isset($args['v']) ? $args['v'] : false;
    }

    $theurl = "youtube.com/watch?v=1337&feature=player_embedded";
    $youtubeid = getYouTubeIdFromURL($theurl);
    echo "'$youtubeid'";
?>
```

Output:

```
'1337'
```

Comment: If it checked out fine, it's definitely possible that it's the Wordpress function causing the problem. I don't want to mess with the core files because I'm afraid I would mess something up and the progress would be negated after each update. Do you know of any way I could trim the whitespace out? I tried a regular trim($youtubeid) but it didn't seem to work (*note* I might be doing it incorrectly)

Comment: `trim($youtubeid)` works just fine for me using the sample you pasted in your question.  Maybe those aren't really space characters you are getting back...?