# How do I get a youtube video ID (PHP)

Tags: php, video, youtube, extract

Given a link from youtube
e.g. `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XHs99iVpnXU`

how do I extract the video id (the v parameter) without it being affected by other parameters such as `feature=`
e.g. `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XHs99iVpnXU&feature=watch&fullscrenn=true` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $variables)
print $variables['v'];
```