# Get some value from url?

Tags: php, arrays, string, youtube

I have this kind of url from youtube, with the value of video

```
$url='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H_IkPia6eBA&';
```

What i need is just to get new string with value of V etc in this case

```
$newstring='H_IkPia6eBA&';
```

I dont know how long V could be, only i need to get that value of V, I have tried

```
$string = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oYyslNuRcwM';
$url = parse_url($string);
parse_str($url['query'], $query);

print_r($query);
```

Tried with this, but in CodeIgniter post, I only get empty array?

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522868/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-id-php)

Comment: Your code works great for me, just copy and pasted, I get: `Array
(
    [v] => oYyslNuRcwM
)`

Comment: Are you sure `$string` is set? What does `var_dump($string);` output? Also, add `ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your PHP code and refresh the page. Does that output any errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there already.

```
<?php
 $string = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oYyslNuRcwM';
 $url = parse_url($string);
 parse_str($url['query'], $query);
 $newstring=$query["v"];   // just this line is missing
 echo $newstring;
?>
```

**[Demo](http://codepad.org/bpV7NJSY)**

But you know something? If the url format is always going to be like that then no need for all those functions. It then can simply be

```
<?php
$url='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H_IkPia6eBA&';
echo str_replace("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=","",$url);
?>
```