# PHP - trimming part of the URL

Tags: php, trim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [regex pattern to get Youtube ID from any Youtube URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594943/regex-pattern-to-get-youtube-id-from-any-youtube-url)

I would like to know how to trim a part of a URL like "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I4_3PVFSUxE&feature=plcp" and it will only output "I4_3PVFSUxE".

So I want to get the code that is after "v=" and delete whatever is after that.

Answer (score 2):

You could use...

```
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);

parse_str($query, $queryParts);

$v = $queryParts['v'];

if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $v = stripslashes($v);
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/G1YxgbyJ).