# Get YouTube video id from embed iframe code

Tags: php, regex, iframe, youtube

I want to get the YouTube video ID from YouTube embed code using preg_match or regex. For a example

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/0gugBiEkLwU?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I want to take the ID `0gugBiEkLwU`

Can anyone tell me how to do this. Really appropriate your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx pattern to get the YouTube video ID from any YouTube URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594943/regex-pattern-to-get-the-youtube-video-id-from-any-youtube-url)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find all Youtube video ids in a string using a regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830387/how-to-find-all-youtube-video-ids-in-a-string-using-a-regex)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using this pattern with a capturing group should give you the string you want:

```
d\/(\w+)\?rel=\d+"
```

example: https://regex101.com/r/kH5kA7/1

Answer (score 4):

You can use :

```
src="\/\/(?:https?:\/\/)?.*\/(.*?)\?rel=\d*"
```

Check Demo **[Here](http://regex101.com/r/vY6eV7)**

**Explanation :**

[image]

Comment: id is not always digit - fails with src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/w-yFtdJ47Mk?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is pretty late, but I came up with something for people who might still be looking.
Since not all Youtube iframe src attributes end in "?rel=", and can sometimes end in another query string or end with a double quote, you can use:

```
/embed\/([\w+\-+]+)[\"\?]/
```

This captures anything after "/embed/" and before the ending double-quote/query string. The selection can include any letter, number, underscore and hyphen.

Here's a demo with multiple examples: https://regex101.com/r/eW7rC1/1

Answer (score 0):

The below function will extract the youtube video id from the all format of youtube urls,

```
function getYoutubeVideoId($iframeCode) {
    
    // Extract video url from embed code
    return preg_replace_callback('/<iframe\s+.*?\s+src=(".*?").*?<\/iframe>/', function ($matches) {
        // Remove quotes
        $youtubeUrl = $matches[1];
        $youtubeUrl = trim($youtubeUrl, '"');
        $youtubeUrl = trim($youtubeUrl, "'");
        // Extract id
        preg_match("/^(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:m\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:(?:watch)?\?(?:.*&)?v(?:i)?=|(?:embed|v|vi|user)\/))([^\?&\"'>]+)/", $youtubeUrl, $videoId);
        return $youtubeVideoId = isset($videoId[1]) ? $videoId[1] : "";
    }, $iframeCode);
    
}

$iframeCode = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/0gugBiEkLwU?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

// Returns youtube video id
echo getYoutubeVideoId($iframeCode);
```