# How to change "Video site link" to "Video embed link" using Laravel

Tags: iframe, video, laravel, youtube, embed

I'm building a social network site with Laravel

I have a section of my site where a user can submit a URL to a video with a form ex. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxxxx

The URL gets saved in the database.

I want to embed the youtube/vimeo player on the page using an iframe.

I can grab the url using `$video->url`

In order to display the iframe I use

```
<iframe width="306" height="200" src={{ $video->url }} frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The space is there but no video. Just blank space. I figure this is because the link is not the embed link youtube provides which should be `//www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxxxx`

Is there a Laravel way to convert site URLs to embed URLs? I don't want to make my users submit the embed URL since most people don't know about it and it's easier for them to just submit the URL in their browser

Comment: what about this : `{{ $video->link + "&output=embed" }}` ?

Comment: Hmm now i get an error saying No query result for model (User model)... strange. I'll have to look more into this error

Comment: I made a mistake. check again with url property. `{{ $video->url + "&output=embed" }}`

Comment: I caught that. but its echoing out 0... src="0"

Comment: Ahem the concatenation operator in PHP is `.`

Comment: ah yes, good point. I no longer get an error, but I still get a blank space. no video

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [grab the id](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9785191/3781701) of youtube video before saving the url to the database.

Then store the embed link:

```
"http://www.youtube.com/embed/$youtube_id"
```