# How to take special part of a url using php

Tags: php

How I can take a special part from a url ? For example i want to take only v=q07isX-Q1-U  from this url http://m.youtube.com/watch?gl=US&hl=en-GB&client=mv-google&feature=m-featured&v=q07isX-Q1-U . Is it possible in php.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392993/php-regex-to-get-youtube-video-id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $values);
if (isset($values['v'])) {
    echo $values['v'];
}
```

http://php.net/parse_url
http://php.net/parse_str

Comment: I like your code but not yet test. Would you plz explain it more?

Comment: Well, please read the manual. `parse_url` parses the URL into separate pieces, `parse_str` parses the query string part of the URL into separate values.

Comment: Thanks for reply. One more question can i use $values['v'] directly in function & print because the url will be $_POST to this page.

Comment: Sorry, not getting what you're asking. `$values['v']` will be a regular variable like any other variable.

Comment: whatever variable you want to put in can be there as the 2nd parameter for parse_str().  doesn't have to be $values.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $_GET["v"]; ?>
```

This should return what is stored in the v= parameter

EDIT: I should note that this only works if your script is receiving the parameters as part of the get request.  Not if you are trying to just parse it as text.

Comment: I'd assume the code is *not* going to run on `m.youtube.com`... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$url = "http://m.youtube.com/watch?gl=US&v=q07isX-Q1-U";
print_r(parse_url($url));
$str= parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);

parse_str($str);
echo $gl;  // US
echo $v; // q07isX-Q1-U

parse_str($str, $output);
echo $output['gl'];  // US
echo $output['v']; // q07isX-Q1-U
?>
```