# how do I store a youtube embed link in a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, youtube

When I save a youtube embed iframe into my database it adds a bunch of slashes when i recall it. Like so below.

```
<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/ycHXRWRKrdA?rel=0\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

its is being stored in a longtext type. what would remove the slashes when I recall it from the database or prevent slashes being stored in the first place

Comment: What technology do you use? You must have a security option enabled that automatically escapes the strings before persisting them into the db (which is not bad actually). One option is to remove those backslashes using regex (e.g. `.replaceAll("\\\\", "")`).

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but why would you store that in such a nasty way? Why don't you store the video's ID only?!

Comment: I assume that this is happening because you use an older version of php than 5.3 and in there the config flag [`magic_quotes_gpc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc) is set to `true`, which makes php do automatic quote escaping on all get, post and cookie values.

Comment: it just seemed logical thing to do. I'm using it to store posts I make with a CMS. what would be a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use PHP, you can use stripslashes().

Alternatively you can base64 encode / decode the code.

Answer (score 6):

Don't save the HTML like that - just save the youtube unique ID and then spit out the HTML and plug in the ID from the database.

[PHP Regex to get youtube video ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392993/php-regex-to-get-youtube-video-id)

Answer (score 1):

once and for all add this in your .htaccess:

```
# disable the automatic-quote-removing from requests
php_value magic_quotes_gpc off
```

you didnt say if you save the youtube url in a JSON in database.
if yes, replace possible quotes via:

```
str_replace('\"','\\"',$url);
```

also, of course its better idea to save just the youtube code as:

```
$eurl = explode("/",$url);
$eurl[sizeof($eurl)-1];     // <-- to database
```