# Convert tags with regular expression

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I wanna convert youtube tags...
my existing tags looks like this:

```
[video=youtube;puineN1UMto]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=puineN1UMto&amp;feature=related[/video]
```

And I want them to convert to:

```
[media=youtube]puineN1UMto[media]
```

How can I do that? Please guide.
Thanks

Comment: you could use answer from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392993/php-regex-to-get-youtube-video-id and use the matches to be place inside the [media=youtube][media] tag

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
Search: %\[video=youtube;([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\].*\[\/video\]%
Replace: [media=youtube]\1[/media]
```

Comment: +1; though I would choose `[^]]` to match `puineN1UMto` and `.*?` to match inside the video tag so that you can match multiple `[video]` tags :)