# Getting the YouTube Video URL in a Variable

Tags: php, variables, youtube

How to get the YouTube video(.flv) path in a PHP variable ..
Suppose from a youtube video url it will fetch the video downloadable url link..something like this:
 `http://tc.v15.cache3.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?algorithm=throttle-factor&burst=40&cp=U0hTSVNRUV9LTUNOM19LS1VIOlZ1V2M5YUd5RVNM&expire=1344363763&factor=1.25&fexp=906430%2C913529%2C915507%2C907217%2C919804%2C920704%2C912806%2C906055%2C924500%2C925701%2C924700%2C911406%2C913547%2C904721%2C920706%2C907344%2C912706%2C900816%2C902518%2C909414&id=5d4df8214f695e43&ip=184.95.55.18&ipbits=8&itag=5&keepalive=yes&key=yt1&ms=au&mt=1344338530&mv=m&signature=C0012A45BF4240C299C6755507BCC6C24F291153.8F40151E7E3331B9524A54F168FB3BF0C4BFFA63&source=youtube&sparams=algorithm%2Cburst%2Ccp%2Cfactor%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&sver=3&upn=OHj8ucDOV7c`
So i will have like this. $vurl= this_types_of_video_url;
any idea?

Answer (score 3):

There is no YouTube Video ID variable in the URL example you put into the question in the first place. Also, `.flv` download sites have been given [cease and desist](http://www.cbsnews.com/8301-501465_162-57456397-501465/google-youtube-blocks-website-that-converts-videos-into-mp3s/) inquire from Google.

If there would be, your way to fetch the URL would be using the [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function which helps you to match a regular expression pattern on the URL.

The other option would be using the [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`parse_str()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) functions.

The method described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3393008/1428773) should set you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Scape the page?

1. Find the player JavaScript-block.
2. Escape the JavaScript-block and extract the player variables.
3. Fetch the query string for the variables.
4. Find the stream map (url_encoded_fmt_stream_map), again, a query string.
5. Iterate through each item in the map, split by comma and again, a query string.
6. Profit!