# Populate Array from database, search inside and extract strings

Tags: php, mysql

I am grabbing from a MySQL database some fields and putting them into an array.
Here is the code:

```
$dataArray = array();

$query_url = "SELECT * FROM videos";
$query_exec = mysql_query($query_url) or die();

while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query_exec)) {
    echo $dataArray[$res['id']] = $res['video'];
    echo "<br />";      
}
```

With this I have the printed list of youtube videos taken from my "videos" table, I am trying to get only the last shortcode of youtube, for example:
Here is the youtube link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sN8grtFUQYs
I want to get only the: sN8grtFUQYs

How can I get them from an array that gets the data from a MySQL database automatically?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Thx for the mysql_* :)
This is a just sample code and trying fast example offline.
I tried etract(), but my big problem is that the array is dynamic

Comment: I usually use mysqli. Thank you again for the reminder

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Regex to get youtube video ID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392993/php-regex-to-get-youtube-video-id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not really efficient but you could explode() it and call end() to get the last result of the array.

```
$dataArray = array();

$query_url = "SELECT * FROM videos";
$query_exec = mysql_query($query_url) or die();

while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query_exec)) {
    echo $dataArray[$res['id']] = end(explode('?v=',$res['video']));
    echo "<br />";      
}
```

Comment: Damn....thank you, I forgot end() :(
Thank you very much (some mins and I can accept the answer)

Answer (score 1):

```
$dataArray = array();

$query_url = "SELECT * FROM videos";
$query_exec = mysql_query($query_url) or die();

while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query_exec)) {
    preg_match( '/[\?\&]v=([^\?\&]+)/', $res['video'], $id );
    echo $dataArray[$res['id']] = $id[1];
    echo "<br />";      
}
```