# Perl Extract Youtube ID from URL with Regex

Tags: regex, perl

I found a great bit of code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392993/php-regex-to-get-youtube-video-id) to extract the ID from a youtube URL in `PHP`.

I'm now having syntax issues converting this regex to `Perl`.

```
preg_match("#(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=v\/)[^&\n]+(?=\?)|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+|(?<=youtu.be/)[^&\n]+#", $link, $matches);
```

This matches the following versions, extracting this portion of the URL: `g6QrR5Uakeg`

```
youtube.com/v/g6QrR5Uakeg
youtube.com/vi/g6QrR5Uakeg
youtube.com/?v=g6QrR5Uakeg
youtube.com/?vi=g6QrR5Uakeg
youtube.com/watch?v=g6QrR5Uakeg
youtube.com/watch?vi=g6QrR5Uakeg
youtu.be/g6QrR5Uakeg
www.youtube.com/v/g6QrR5Uakeg?feature=autoshare&version=3&autohide=1&autoplay=1
```

Comment: Youtube video ID's aren't {vidid}, you can't match for that.

Comment: If you want help, you're going to have to post examples of what you want, and what works and doesn't work.

Comment: "Having issues get the syntax to work when converting this regex to Perl". What issues? Syntax errors? Regex errors? We need to see code so we know how to help.

Comment: Personally, I define "great code" as things that do not give me a headache when I look at it.

Comment: {vidid} is merely for example, thought that was apparent. I'll edit post with a fake id

Comment: Regex is probably not your best bet for this, [URI::Split](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/URI-1.60/URI/Split.pm) seems like this is the very purpose it's been designed for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps,

```
my ($id) = $url =~ m! (?: \bv i? [/=] | be/ ) (\w+) !x;
```

in english, 
match word boundary, then letter 'v', followed by 'i' occurring 0 or 1 times.
Then match character '/' or '='.

| stands for "or", so if matching has failed by now, try with chars 'be/'.

If anything of the above succeeded, use \w+ to match ID we're looking for.
(\w is word class which stands for 0-9 A-Z a-z and _)