# Wordpress - Ajax and jQuery.serialize - how to access?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

i use the wordpress built-in ajax implementation in one of my plugins as follows:

```
jQuery('#form_data_voting').submit(function() {
        jQuery.post(
            ajax_object.ajax_url,
            {
                action : 'voting_save',
                value : jQuery('#form_data_voting').serialize(),
            },
                function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
        );//get
});
```

And the function in PHP looks like follows:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_voting_save', function () {
    var_dump($_POST['value']);          
    die();
});//wp_ajax_voting_save
```

I then see in the dump that all relevant fields are in one string - thanks to the serialize() function. But the problem here is, that it is stored behind the "value" variable and i can't get it out there. The string looks like this: `name=testname&tel=3883838`. I can't access the name via: `$_POST['name']` or `$_POST['value']['name']`.

How can i access `name` and `tel` as POST-variables in the wordpress ajax environment or is that not possible and i have to create name and tel as values in the js-file and have to leave `serialize()` out of the function?

Would be great if anybody has experiences this before and can share the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

thanks VukBG - for my example not `parse_url` but `parse_str` is sufficient:

```
    parse_str($_POST['value'], $my_array_of_vars);
    print_r($my_array_of_vars);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function. I think that is what you are looking for.

You can also see a good example for this function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392993/php-regex-to-get-youtube-video-id)

Comment: Serializing an html form does not return a url, it returns a string.

Comment: parse_url() takes string as an argument