# Extracting ID From YouTube URL with ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

Following this [tutorial by Ray Camden](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/7/5/Quick-little-regex-example--Youtube-video-from-URL)...

Trying to fetch the ID from the YouTube URL:

```
<cfset regex = "^(?:[^?]+\?v=|[^v]+/v/)([^&##/]+).*|http://youtu.be/">;

<cfset videoid = rereplace(u, regex, "\1" ) />
```

But the `youtu.be` does not seems to work here; other YouTube URLs seems fine.

Comment: ray mentioned at the end of the post how to handle `youtu.be`, simply detect whether the url contains `youtu.be`, and if it does, use `listlast`. Not quite sure if it's worth it to complicate the regexp to have it handle both

Comment: code worked fine, so some other typo error was there. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
<cfset regex = "#(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=v\/)[^&\n]+(?=\?)|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+|(?<=youtu.be/)[^&\n]+#">;
<cfset videoid = rereplace(u, regex, "\1" ) />
```

Source [PHP Regex to get youtube video ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392993/php-regex-to-get-youtube-video-id#answer-6121972)

Comment: getting an error using this: ` Invalid CFML construct found on line 9 at column 21.
ColdFusion was looking at the following text:

?

The CFML compiler was processing:

    An expression beginning with (, on line 9, column 20.This message is usually caused by a problem in the expressions structure.
    An expression beginning with /", on line 9, column 18.This message is usually caused by a problem in the expressions structure.
    A cfset tag beginning on line 9, column 4.`

Comment: i think the start of coldfusion based regex is like that you written above,

Comment: I dont have CodeFusion to check but with a minor change like escaping a forward slash would do the trick. Try `#(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=v\/)[^&\n]+(?=\?)|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+|(?<=youtu.be\/)[^&\n]+#`

Comment: pound is coldfusion reserved(#), so not sure it will work, but trying

Comment: still getting same issue