# How to extract Youtube thumbnail from Textarea on post just like Facebook

Tags: php, youtube

have tried searching the solution to this question here but couldn't find the exact solution to my problem. what i want to do is to display the thumbnail of youtube video link posted in the textarea field of my website without having a separate  input field for video urls just like its done on facebook where you post a youtube link to the same status box and it shows the thumbnail of the video.

Thanks alot

Comment: To get a youtube video thumbail you can use `http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/0.jpg` , options are 1.jpg , 2.jpg , 3.jpg

Comment: @PedroLobito how will i be able to filter it from the post since i will be using $_POST[''] to post contents from the textrea input to my database

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392993/php-regex-to-get-youtube-video-id