# Flutter Dart : How to extract youtube video ID from video URL?

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

How to use dart regex to extract YouTube video ID from video URL?

**Example URL**

> ```
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SEkUienM2oY&t=1265s
> ```

or

> ```
> https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=SEkUienM2oY&t=1265s
> ```

**Return**

> ```
> SEkUienM2oY&t=1265s
> ```

Its working for me

```
  String getVideoID(String url) {
    url = url.replaceAll("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=", "");
    url = url.replaceAll("https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=", "");
    return url;
  }
```

but how to do this with Regex??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all our URLs are similar to our input string in the question, we can simply just extract those IDs with an expression similar to:

```
.*\?v=(.+?)&.+
```

and our desired output is in this capturing group: `(.+?)`

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/w8NViq/1/)

#### Reference

It seems we'd have [11 alphanumeric chars `[A-Za-z0-9]{11}`](https://regex101.com/r/iiAQDJ/1/) for that ID. That might be something unique if you'd want to design sophisticated expressions:

- [PHP Regex to get youtube video ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392993/php-regex-to-get-youtube-video-id)
- [How do I get the YouTube video ID from a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452546/how-do-i-get-the-youtube-video-id-from-a-url)
- [RegEx pattern to get the YouTube video ID from any YouTube URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594943/regex-pattern-to-get-the-youtube-video-id-from-any-youtube-url)
- [Validating Youtube URL using Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13476060/validating-youtube-url-using-regex)
- [Regular expression for YouTube video Id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42440678/regular-expression-for-youtube-video-id)
- [Regex for youtube URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377262/regex-for-youtube-url)

Comment: URL structure with embeded video is missing with this regex.

Comment: does not work with https://youtu.be/S5ZjEtC2aNo

Answer (score 11):

Without regex, I hope this will work perfectly
**Add this dependency into your pubspec.yaml file**

> `youtube_player_flutter: ^6.1.0+4`

```
try {

    videoIdd = YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId("your url here");
    print('this is '+videoId);

  } on Exception catch (exception) {

    // only executed if error is of type Exception
    print('exception');

  } catch (error) {

    // executed for errors of all types other than Exception
     print('catch error');
   //  videoIdd="error";

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Such Regex can parse Youtube video Urls **without** timing as well

```
.*\?v=(.+?)($|[\&])
```

Complete example in dart:

```
  String? _getYoutubeVideoIdByURL (String url) {
    final regex = RegExp(r'.*\?v=(.+?)($|[\&])', caseSensitive: false);

    try {
      if (regex.hasMatch(url)) {
        return regex.firstMatch(url)!.group(1);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: here what is "text"?

Comment: i get a yellow error saying "Redundant character escape '\&' in RegExp"

Answer (score 2):

```dart
static String convertUrlToId(String url, {bool trimWhitespaces = true}) {
  assert(url?.isNotEmpty ?? false, 'Url cannot be empty');
  if (!url.contains("http") && (url.length == 11)) return url;
  if (trimWhitespaces) url = url.trim();

  for (var exp in [
    RegExp(
        r"^https:\/\/(?:www\.|m\.)?youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([_\-a-zA-Z0-9]{11}).*$"),
    RegExp(
        r"^https:\/\/(?:www\.|m\.)?youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com\/embed\/([_\-a-zA-Z0-9]{11}).*$"),
    RegExp(r"^https:\/\/youtu\.be\/([_\-a-zA-Z0-9]{11}).*$")
  ]) {
    Match match = exp.firstMatch(url);
    if (match != null && match.groupCount >= 1) return match.group(1);
  }

  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static String? convertUrlToId(String url, {bool trimWhitespaces = true}) {
    if (!url.contains("http") && (url.length == 11)) return url;
    if (trimWhitespaces) url = url.trim();

    for (var exp in [
      RegExp(
          r"^https:\/\/(?:www\.|m\.)?youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([_\-a-zA-Z0-9]{11}).*$"),
      RegExp(
          r"^https:\/\/(?:www\.|m\.)?youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com\/embed\/([_\-a-zA-Z0-9]{11}).*$"),
      RegExp(r"^https:\/\/youtu\.be\/([_\-a-zA-Z0-9]{11}).*$")
    ]) {
      Match? match = exp.firstMatch(url);
      if (match != null && match.groupCount >= 1) return match.group(1);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of how and why this solves the problem. Also it seems very similar to solution by @shanu12joshi. It would be good to describe how it differs.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to cover all YouTube URL variants try this:

```
^(?:(?:https?:)?\/\/)?(?:(?:(?:www|m(?:usic)?)\.)?youtu(?:\.be|be\.com)\/(?:shorts\/|live\/|v\/|e(?:mbed)?\/|watch(?:\/|\?(?:\S+=\S+&)*v=)|oembed\?url=https?%3A\/\/(?:www|m(?:usic)?)\.youtube\.com\/watch\?(?:\S+=\S+&)*v%3D|attribution_link\?(?:\S+=\S+&)*u=(?:\/|%2F)watch(?:\?|%3F)v(?:=|%3D))?|www\.youtube-nocookie\.com\/embed\/)([\w-]{11})[\?&#]?\S*$
```

It's a RegExp from a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78172756/11194000) for any known YouTube URL (also music.*, shorts/, live/, e/ embed/, v/, *-nocookie etc.). Also catches video ID.

If you want you can restrict the video ID further with [Glenn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41988283/11194000) instead of `([\w-]{11})`.