# how can i get youtube video id with php referer?

Tags: php, http-referer, referer

I want to track where exactly is click from youtube video. U have tried with this code. But its return only "www.youtube.com/". I want to print this "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_bnur3gHJ0s"

```
<?
$whr = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
print_r($whr);
?>
```

Comment: If you don't get it from the HTTP_REFERER, you're out of luck. It's also probably because it's behind HTTPS. Then you usually only get the hostname, not the full URL.

Comment: is there another way?

Comment: No. That's called privacy.

Comment: thank you for answering.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Regex is probably your best method of choice. 
There's a post here that should benefit you.

[PHP Regex to get youtube video ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392993/php-regex-to-get-youtube-video-id)

Comment: In what way shape or form would regex solve this issue? The OP states that the referrer only contains `www.youtube.com`. That's all the OP gets.

Answer (score 0):

Because of HTTPS, you dont (always) get a referer. You could check with `print_r($_SERVER)` if there is something else, but don't rely on it too much.

A better solution would be to add a referer as get parameter, eg:
- example.com/somepage?ref=youtube_description
- example.com/somepage?ref=video&video=12345