# how to check if youtube url exist or not in laravel?

Tags: laravel, url, youtube

I want to check if entered URL exist on YouTube or not before saving that URL in my database

I am using this code

```
$url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KeaoSIKaxeg';
if(preg_match('/http:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=[^&]+/', $url)) 
{
    dd('match');
}
else 
{
    dd('not match');
}
```

I have tried everything but nothing works. It always returns 'not match' even if the URL is valid.

Comment: Did you try something [like this ?](https://gist.github.com/petk/813270d801bad54d3cc4)

Comment: Try [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392993/php-regex-to-get-youtube-video-id/17030234)

Answer (score 2):

```
$headers = get_headers('http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KeaoSIKaxeg');
if (!strpos($headers[0], '200')) {
    echo "The YouTube video you entered does not exist";
}
```

Comment: Nice, will tell you if the video actually exists, too

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to match against `http://`, not `https://`:

```
$url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KeaoSIKaxeg';
if(preg_match('/https:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=[^&]+/', $url)) {
     dd('match');
}
else {
    dd('not match');
}
```