# Embed youtube videos in an input Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I am looking for some package or the correct way that the user can through an input add the url of a youtube video and it is added correctly and previewed.

My code Create:

```
$properties = Property::create([
    'video' =>  $this->video,
])
```

View:

```
<input wire:model="video" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Url youtube">
```

If I add it as a url the video is not shown and it previews the url.
it works if i insert it as iframe.

Could you help me how it could be done by directly inserting the address of the video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [YouTube Embedded Players and Player Parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters) page, embedded videos' URL should be in this format `https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID` and be inside an iframe:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="360"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autoplay=1&origin=http://example.com"
  frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

So you need to extract the `VIDEO_ID` from the. I'll borrow some code from [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3393008) and suggest this code:

```
$url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4kxS1ksqtw&feature=relate';
parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $my_array_of_vars);
echo $my_array_of_vars['v'];

// Output: C4kxS1ksqtw
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, once you get the C4kxS1ksqtw output you should insert it into the ID. and at http://example.com the full address? I would have to have two fields in the table one for the ID and one for the full URL?

Comment: ready works perfect! I did it as you indicated but with the iframe as follows: <iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/{!! $propiedad->video !!}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> thanks!!