# How to check if YouTube video exists using YouTube Data API v3

Tags: php, api, youtube, cron

I have developed a website where users can add and embed YouTube videos. I store the YouTube ID in a database.

I am facing an issue where videos are being removed by YouTube, generally down to copyright/DMCA, private videos or users deleting them.

I would like to run an hourly CRON job that checks if these videos still exist using a PHP script but I can't find any resources on this.

Could anybody help?

Peter

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check if a video exists on YouTube, using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383073/how-do-i-check-if-a-video-exists-on-youtube-using-php)

Comment: Try downloading url data, and check for words like "not found" or "invalid url", if you cloudn't find any direct solution

Comment: This wouldn't be suitable because video titles might contain these words and YouTube could change their wording in a moment without warning. I would like a solid method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better solution:

```
if (sizeof($videoResponse['items'])) {
    // Video exist, do stuff     
}
```

### Source: [verify if video exist with youtube api v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29166402/verify-if-video-exist-with-youtube-api-v3)

You can check if your **videoResponse** is an object:

```
$videoResponse = $youtube->videos->listVideos('snippet,statistics', array(
    'id' => $videoId 
));    

if (is_object($videoResponse['items'][0])) {
    // Video exist, do stuff     
}
```

Or check if it is **!empty**:

```
if (!empty($videoResponse['items'][0])) {
    // Video exist, do stuff     
}
```

You can actually check for privacy status too:

```
$videoResponse = $youtube->videos->listVideos('status', array(
    'id' => $videoId 
));    

$privacyStatus = $videoResponse['items'][0]['status']['privacyStatus'];
```