# video id validation for youtube api

Tags: javascript, php, youtube, youtube-api

Since version 2 (**v2**) of the **Youtube API** has been depreciated, the following method no longer works for checking if a **video id** is actually valid:

obtaining the results from:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/videoID
```

**QUESTION:**

What alternative method is there to validate a video id?

**MY RESEARCH:**

I'm not sure if what I have found is related or not, but the [youtube api documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) gives some feedback on the following method:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos
```

I'm not sure how to use it and am currently killing neurons and drinking coffee shots trying to deduce if this is in fact an alternative method of validating if a video id is legit or not, and in the case that it were, how to use it.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29166402/verify-if-video-exist-with-youtube-api-v3