# How to validate youtube video ids? gdata.youtube.com is not working

Tags: javascript, validation, video, youtube

I am trying to validate youtube video ids..get some info from [youtube-validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742813/how-to-validate-youtube-video-ids)...but its not working seems http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID  is  no more active link or depricated. Any help would be more appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Youtube Google API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/), specifically the `youtube.videos.list` service. If you issue a request such as `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id&id=VIDEO_ID`, (you must be authenticated) it should return a response with the video info under the `items` attribute. If `items` is empty, a video with that id does not exist. For example, a valid video may return a JSON response like this:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"fpJ9onbY0Rl_LqYLG6rOCJ9h9N8/2sdqvy58GwqpgneamWQjMdcDsqc\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"fpJ9onbY0Rl_LqYLG6rOCJ9h9N8/u5C_LXE-00OOvmXch-wqbcTQQ5Q\"",
   "id": "VapbvTq8GOE"
  }
 ]
}
```

But if the video id is invalid, items will be empty `[]`